# Find endomorphisms a, b such that ab-ba=identity

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let *V* be the space of infinitely differentiable functions from R to R.  Find endomorphisms *a*, *b* of *V* such that *ab - ba = id(V)*.

This is clearly impossible for finite dimensional vector spaces, but I do not know how to find appropriate endomorphisms in this case.  I am inclined to use the property that the functions in *V* are infinitely differentiable, but this has not worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M:V\to V, f(x)\mapsto xf(x)$, and $D:V\to V, f(x)\mapsto f'(x)$, then
$$(D\circ M-M\circ D)(f)=(xf)'-xf'=f$$
That is $D\circ M-M\circ D=I$.

Comment: Damn. This is one of those answers you see, and just go "how would I have thought of this..."